# BufferedReader Java , replace all occurences in CSV file

Tags: java, csv, replace, bufferedreader

I've tried looking for other solution but can't seem to figure it out. 
I have a csv file and I need to replace every line which has a NaN value to a integer value. Shouldn't be too hard but can't seem to get it working.

I have the following

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("data/submission.csv"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("data/test2.csv");
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        { 
            line = line.replaceAll("NaN","2.5");
            fw.write(line, 0, line.length());

        } 
        fr.close();
        fw.close();

    }
}
```

Yet this seems to completely replace every column and put it into one single row. Optionally I would also like all the whitespaces on the lines to be removed. That is,

Should become

1 , 2.5097082975695546

2 , 1.8214176758412945

3 , NaN

4 , 2.756971983384317

5 , 1.6845822125042142

tried doing this with line = line.replaceAll(" ", ""). 
But again, messes up the format real bad

1,2.5097082975695546

2,1.8214176758412945

3,2.5

4,2.756971983384317

5,1.6845822125042142

Comment: what is the input and expected output?

Comment: What is the issue with the replacement of spaces?

Comment: Use `line.replace("NaN", "2.5").replace(" ","");` instead of `line.replaceAll("NaN","2.5")`

Comment: `replaceAll();` uses regex not direct input.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the output on a single row, just add the line terminations:

```
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    { 
        line = line.replaceAll("NaN","2.5") + "\\r\\n";
        fw.write(line, 0, line.length());

    }
```

Comment: Both this solution and the solution below just seems to be adding \r\n(appendingvalue) behind every column entry

Comment: Why would you use replaceAll that is for use with a regex when you have more than just one char sequence to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do `fw.write(line, 0, line.length());` without the new  line characters `\n` or `\r`.

Maybe edit folowing line of code in your while loop to fix the problem:

`fw.write((line + "\\n"), 0, (line + "\\n").length());`

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this with the Files api.

```
List<String> inputLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("data/submission.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

List<String> fixedLines = new ArrayList<>(inputLines.size());

for(String line: inputLines){
    fixedLines.add(line.replace("NaN", "2.5"));
}

Files.write(
             Paths.get("data/test2.csv"), 
             fixedLines,
             StandardCharset.UTF_8,
             StandardOpenOption.CREATE
            );
```

This will use the platform specific line break. So you don't have to.

If you also want to remove spaces you can chain the replace calls as such.

```
fixedLines.add(line.replace("NaN", "2.5").replace(" ", ""));
```

Comment: This one solved the issue indeed! Thank you so much, never would have been able to think of this myself